# Copying a column to a new workbook sheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy an existing column from a sheet to a column in a new workbook.

The code that I tried:

```
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy Destination:=NewBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2)
```

This is creating a sheet but no values are copied!
This code works if I copy to another sheet in same workbook.

How should I create a new sheet in the `NewBook` and target columns in that `sheet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remember the old book, otherwise `Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)` will refer to the first column of the `Sheet1` of the newly added one since it is the `ActiveWorkbook` in this moment (so you actually copy something, but that something is an empty column):

```
Sub qwerty()
    Set w1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    w1.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy Destination:=NewBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2)
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This will rename the sheet in the new workbook and then perform the copy:

```
Sub qwerty2()
    Set w1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Report"
    w1.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Columns(2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Gary is it possible  to copy it to sheet name "Report" in new workbook?